# Search bar isnt contained in its div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This search bar that I made continues all the way through the right of the page for no reason. It was working yesterday where it was a search bar and a Go! button next to it, and I havent changed anything from yesterday and now it is broken.

```
<form role="form" id="form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
        <label for="search"> </label>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2">
        <input type="text"
            class="form-control" name="search" id="search"
            placeholder="Search for..." />
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="submit"> Go!
            </button> </div> </div> </div>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want it to fit across the whole div?

Comment: Please post your CSS as well.

Comment: I would recommend posting it in a jsfiddle, those are always super useful as it also lets people edit and test it on the fly without having to run it on their own

Comment: Cannot reproduce - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rVPwWv